# Can't Change BIOS Settings

Tags: bios

I have a server that runs Ubuntu. I'm trying to enable AC power loss restoration in the BIOS, but for whatever reason I can't change that setting nor any other setting on the Power Management tab. (This is an AMI BIOS.)

At first glance, it looks like I have only user level access (I assume this is the issue), but I'm not sure what to do to enable administrator access: I've already reset the password using the pins on the motherboard.

Comment: Which motherboard are you running, AMI is in many computers.